# Memory increases and is never reclaimed when logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When experimenting with logging in ASP Net 7 i noticed that the memory increases every time a log statement is hit, and this memory never seem to be garbage collected. Here's an example:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHostedService<Background>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", (ILogger<Program> logger)  =>
{
    return "Hello World!";
});

app.Run();
```

And a background service:

```
public class Background : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Background> _logger;

    public Background(ILogger<Background> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Doing some background work..");
        }
    }
}
```

In this extreme example the memory usage increases by 1 MB every few seconds, but the same effect can be seen where logging happens less frequently.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just how logging works?

Comment: You have tight loop. Just don't do that. If you profile the app for a bit, you'll probably see GC runs.

Comment: It's currently at 265 MB and still increasing after running for 15 min. I see the same effect when adding say, a 1 second delay in the loop (it just increases much more slowly)

Comment: GC will take care as soon as you need the money, erm I mean memory - as soon as your application needs the memory.

Comment: Ok interesting, any way to trigger that? An endpoint that allocated some memory for example?

Comment: Don't. This is rather useless code. Just don't care _for now_ and have your code do something useful. Either the problem vanishes (which I am anticipating) or you need to deal with it _when_ it becomes an _actual_ problem. As-is this is expected behavior and nothing to worry about (for _now_).

Comment: @Q-bertsuit the code you posted is the leak and doesn't need any trigger. You're allocating new log events at 100M times per second. That's little different from `while(true){ new byte[128];}`. These will remain in memory until the garbage collection runs. Just don't use such code.

Comment: `never seem to be garbage collected.` it *is* garbage collected, just not immediatelly. The cost of collecting millions of orphaned objects, and the buffers they were held in, will be significant. The application may appear to freeze when that happens as [server mode GC threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc) have the highest priority

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This example was just to show how you can increase the memory very quickly. A more realistic example could be to use a BackgroundService where you sleep 1 second, then throw, catach and log an exception. This will also increase the memory usage with 1 MB every minute or so until the app is using hundreds of megabytes.

Comment: Use a realistic example that reproduces the problem then, including the actual logging configuration and skinks. If what you claim was true every ASP.NET Core developer would have noticed. 1 MB/sec is too much (16 KB per event) and almost certainly caused by the configuration and sinks you use and quite possibly the messages you log.

Comment: How did you measure memory consumption? Did you run the application as a standalone or did you try to debug it in Visual Studio? The debugger keeps track of all allocated objects along with metadata, resulting in larger memory consumption.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah, that could explain it. I was running it with the debugger